# Is this structure being used in English: "Can you be free not to do something"?

Tags: grammar, questions, negation

On an Instagram page, I heard of a structure being used when you actually **ask someone not to do something**. The structure was: **"Can you be free not to Infinitive...?"**

For example:

> Can you be free not to nag a lot?

I know that he meant to transfer the concept of:

> Would you please not nag a lot?

But I searched on the web and couldn't find any such structure, and as these guys have had a few mistakes in their lessons before I thought here would be the best place to ask.

Comment: The only results from a Google search, bound by quote marks, for "Can you be free not to" are a handful of results about free will. The construction you propose does not seem to be standard.

Comment: It's weird but legit syntax/semantics.

Answer (score 0):

*Can you be free not to X* is a grammatical but rather unlikely way of saying "Do you have the freedom not to X?", or more directly "Are you compelled to X"?

It is a question not a request, and I cannot imagine a context in which it will be interpreted as "Please will you not X".

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is correct. It does sound awkward, though.

Should you wish to be cute, you might try this:

"Would it be too much of a burden for you to stop nagging?"